# Elastic beanstalk loadbalancer configure redirect from http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to configure the Elastic Beanstalk load balancer to accept connections from both http and https, but in the case of http, redirect it to https?.  Is it possible to configure this via the AWS web console without additional extensions files or server side filters?

Example: accessing `http_google_com` redirects you to `https_google_com`.

**Our Configuration**
We are using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (tomcat) for hosting our application.
SSL certificate is configured and https is enabled.
Application is accessible through both http and https.

**In Configuration -> Load Balancer we have:**

- Listener port: 80
- Protocol: http
- Secure listener port: 443
- Protocol: https
- SSL certificate ID: *ssl_certificate_id*

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible via the AWS load balancer, you can either do it at the server level by *permanently* redirecting http traffic to https (in server configuration files), or you can do it at the DNS level depending on where your nameservers are hosted.

Route53 does not enable url redirection, Cloudflare does as well as others.